# sphinx, rinohtype: Page Break after every section

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, rinohtype

I want a page break after every chapter and every section.

We can get page breaks in restructured text, anywhere we want using:

```
.. raw::pdf

    PageBreak
```

The good thing is this works both with `rst2pdf` as well as `rinohtype`. However, the advantage with rinohtype is we can achieve the same without adding the above code manually after every section using `stylesheets`.

I am just not sure how we can do that using stylesheets, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Using a custom style sheet, you can force page breaks **before** arbitrary sections by setting the [`page_break`](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/style/rinoh.structure.SectionStyle.html?highlight=page_break#rinoh.structure.SectionStyle.page_break) style attribute (in the upcoming 0.5.0 release, `page_break` can be set on any flowable, not just sections).

To insert a page break at an arbitrary point:

1. Indicate where to insert the page break:

   - or using the [`class`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class) directive (or [`rst-class`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html?highlight=class#id2) in Sphinx) before a body element, or
   - assign a class to a directive by setting the [`:class:`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#common-options) attribute
2. Define a style with a selector matching the class name. This is achieved by means of the *has_class* selector attribute.

The page break will be inserted before the corresponding element.

Here's an example, assuming you're using rinohtype [0.4.3.dev1](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/releases/tag/v0.4.3.dev1) or later:

**Your reStructuredText file**:

```
.. image:: images/screenshot.png
   :class: page-break

A regular paragraph.

.. rst-class:: page-break

This paragraph will trigger a page break.
```

**Your** [**custom style sheet**](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/basicstyling.html#extending-an-existing-style-sheet):

```
[page-break-paragraph : Paragraph(has_class="page-break")]
base = default
page_break = any

[page-break-image : Image(has_class="page_break")]
base = image
page_break = any
```

Note that the newly defined styles will also determine the styling of the page-breaking element. To style them like other elements in the document, you need to set their *base* style to the default style. Refer to the [style log](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/elementstyling.html#style-logs) to figure out which styles these are.

See [issue #186](https://github.com/brechtm/rinohtype/issues/186) for some more details about page breaks in reStructuredText and rinohtype.

Comment: Thanks for this, the same method can as well be used to remove a page break if you dont want one